# How to replace select with range offset?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that goes through a suspended list on a file and copies the data from a worksheets to another for each item in the worksheet.

Since there are 200 items in the list, and roughly 200 copy and paste operations, it's taking too long to run.

I'm trying to optimize, removing copy and paste, and select.

In my old code, I used range and offset, to repeat some operations, and now I can't use them, so I don't know how to rewrite the code.

This is the old code

```vb
Sheets("Motor").Select
Range("A140").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Registros_Saidas_RS1").Select
MyRange.Offset(0, -3).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
```

This is what I'm trying

```vb
Sheets("Registros_Saidas_RS1").MyRange.Offset(0, -3).Value = Sheets("Motor").Range("A140").Value
```

I get an error that I can't use this method.

Comment: If you are not in the 4th column or greater you cannot offset -3 as the column doesn’t exist.

Comment: MyRange is E2
"Set MyRange = Range("E2")"

Comment: MyRange is an object not a property of that Worksheet.Try `MyRange.Offset(0, -3).Value =`

Comment: Also, when you do `Set MyRange = Range("E2)` it assumes the Range is from the ActiveSheet. To specify the sheet for that range, add it like `Set MyRange = Sheets("Registros_Saidas_RS1").Range("E2")`.

Comment: Hey Victor, 
avoid selects whenever you are able to. Target the cells directly.
This for example sets the value of row 1, col 1 in the first worksheet with the value of the second worksheet.  

`Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value = Worksheets(2).Cells(1,1).Value`

This will be faster by a huge factor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the Selects like this

```vb
' acts on the ActiveWorkbook.  Is that what you want?
Sheets("Motor").Range("A140").Copy
' requires MyRange to have been previously set to the required range
MyRange.Offset(0, -3).PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
    Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks :=False, _
    Transpose:=True
```

Then you can use

```
MyRange.Offset(0, -3).Value = _
Sheets("Motor").Range("A140") _
.Resize(MyRange.Rows.Count, MyRange.Columns.Count).Value
```